# Segmentation fault while debuggin a C# Azure Function in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-durable-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

Developing locally a bunch of Azure functions using

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Visual Studio Code
- C#/.NET Core

Everything was working great.  I was able to develop and debug my Azure functions locally and then deploy them to Azure. However a day ago, I upgraded from `netcoreapp2.2` to `netcorepp3.1`.  Here is my current `settings.json`

```
{
  "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": "bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish",
  "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "C#",
  "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~3",
  "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "azureFunctions.preDeployTask": "publish",
  "azureFunctions.templateFilter": "Verified"
}
```

Now I can still start the local debug session by pressing `F5`.  But when I attempt an http request against the `localhost:7071` API address, the debugger session terminates with the following message:

```sh
...
[7/30/2020 8:21:32 PM] f4f4622abc054ed29ac69f1210a204a8: Function 'GetScorecardsByActionTargetType (Orchestrator)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. IsReplay: False. Output: (332 bytes). State: Completed. HubName: PolTrackTestHubV5. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.2.2. SequenceNumber: 8.
[7/30/2020 8:21:32 PM] Executed 'GetScorecardsByActionTargetType' (Succeeded, Id=11f2a673-851e-4afb-9ed6-81f6e3eefc8d)
Stack overflow.
/d/Users/xxx/AppData/Roaming/npm/func: line 14:  2125 Segmentation fault      node "$basedir/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/lib/main.js" "$@"       
The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-c', 'func host start'" terminated with exit code: 139.
```

Any ideas as to what broke during the upgrade (I assume the upgrade is what caused it)?

EDIT:

I commented out the new function (an orchestration) I am working on.  Instead I tried to run in the debugger one of the older orchestrations that used to work before the upgrade and that I have not changed. This older function is in the same local functions project as the new one.

Here is the Terminal Window transcript:

```sh
[7/31/2020 3:30:48 AM] Task hub worker started. Latency: 00:00:02.1744949. InstanceId: . Function: . HubName: PolTrackTestHubV5. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.2.2. SequenceNumber: 1.
[7/31/2020 3:30:48 AM] Host started (2892ms)
[7/31/2020 3:30:48 AM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\Users\xxx\Documents\VisSources\PolTrackCosmosDbFunctions\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[7/31/2020 3:30:53 AM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000B1FC0ED8'.
[7/31/2020 3:32:36 AM] Executing HTTP request: {
[7/31/2020 3:32:36 AM]   "requestId": "425ae07f-7bb8-4c54-beb7-d0c1eb43b6ba",
[7/31/2020 3:32:36 AM]   "method": "GET",
[7/31/2020 3:32:36 AM]   "uri": "/api/action-info-docs/get-one/asdfasdfasdfasdf"
[7/31/2020 3:32:36 AM] }
[7/31/2020 3:32:37 AM] Executing 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration_HttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', 
Id=c67317dd-3f7e-4eab-89ef-2d3bfe155597)
[7/31/2020 3:32:37 AM] c3879f9bdd5f4665952b319a48b81eb7: Function 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration (Orchestrator)' scheduled. Reason: NewInstance. IsReplay: False. State: Scheduled. HubName: PolTrackTestHubV5. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.2.2. SequenceNumber: 2.
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] Started GetActionInfoDocOrchestration orchestration with ID = 'c3879f9bdd5f4665952b319a48b81eb7'.
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] Executing 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration' (Reason='', Id=7d29ec59-3cf6-467b-8cd3-a0d50d2b8eb4)
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] c3879f9bdd5f4665952b319a48b81eb7: Function 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration (Orchestrator)' started. IsReplay: False. Input: (72 bytes). State: Started. HubName: PolTrackTestHubV5. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.2.2. SequenceNumber: 3.
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] Running GetActionInfoDocOrchestration.
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] c3879f9bdd5f4665952b319a48b81eb7: Function 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration (Orchestrator)' completed. ContinuedAsNew: False. 
IsReplay: False. Output: (48 bytes). State: Completed. HubName: PolTrackTestHubV5. AppName: . SlotName: . ExtensionVersion: 2.2.2. SequenceNumber: 
4.
[7/31/2020 3:32:59 AM] Executed 'GetActionInfoDocOrchestration' (Succeeded, Id=7d29ec59-3cf6-467b-8cd3-a0d50d2b8eb4)
Stack overflow.
```

At this point the worker thread is paused on `Stack Overflow` exception.  The call stack contains a large number of exceptions similar to this
[image]

EDIT #2
[image: Call Stack]

EDIT #3

Http Trigger code (the function takes one string argument called docuemntId)

```cs
        [FunctionName(THIS_ORCHESTRATION + "_HttpStart")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "action-info-docs/get-one/{documentId}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            string documentId, ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(THIS_ORCHESTRATION, null, documentId);

            log.LogInformation($"Started {THIS_ORCHESTRATION} orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            DurableOrchestrationStatus status;
            while (true)
            {
                status = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
                if (status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed ||
                    status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Failed ||
                    status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Terminated)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, status.Output);
        }
```

**EDIT #4**

As suggested below, I changed the Http trigger of the orchestration I am calling from `[DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter` `[DurableClient] IDurableClient starter`.  There are five other orchestrations in this project that I have not changed.

After the `Stack Overflow` message, I also get the following message after the debug session terminates:
`The terminal process "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe '-c', 'func host start'" terminated with exit code: 233.`

**EDIT #5**

I did make the change from `IDurableOrchestrationClient` to `IDurableClient` to all six of the orchestrations in my functions project.  Still get the same error.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I'd be happy to, but code for what? It's an orchestration that calls an activity.

Comment: Can you show the callstack, this will give us an idea where stackoverflow exception is happening?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts just added a screenshot of the call stack to the question.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Could you share the types that are the input for the function ? Is there any recursive type ?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts The function takes only one string parameter.  I have added the Http trigger code to the end of the question.  This particular function (orchestration) is one of my older ones that had worked fine both locally and in Azure until I did the 2.2 to 3.1 `netcoreapp` upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by this code in the `HttpStart` function of the orchestration:

```cs
            DurableOrchestrationStatus status;
            while (true)
            {
                status = await starter.GetStatusAsync(instanceId);
                if (status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed ||
                    status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Failed ||
                    status.RuntimeStatus == OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Terminated)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, status.Output);
```

The `Stack Overflow` exception went away after I replaced the above code with

```cs
  return await starter.WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change **[DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter** to **[DurableClient] IDurableClient starter** and give it a try ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that and it does not seem to make any difference.  I still get the same `stack overflow` message.  Just to be clear, I made the change only to the orchestration whose endpoint I call in the debug session.  There are five other orchestrations in the same functions project that I have not changed. Should I make this change to all of them?

Comment: I did make the change to all six of the orchestrations in this functions project.  Still get the same error.

Comment: @ebhh2001- Glad to know that you were able to resolve the issue ,you can additionally look at -                                                                                                                                            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, orchestrationId);                                             this will expose the HTTP Management APIs you can then query statusQueryGetUri to get the updated status of the function this way you wouldn't  have to wait till completion of the function.

Comment: Aditya Singh -thanks for the suggestion.  I admit I am a bit unclear on whether to use `CreateCheckStatusResponse` or `WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync`.  The orchestration returns a JSON document to the client that did an http GET against the endpoint URL.  Will the client still get the JSON result if I use `CreateCheckStatusResponse`?  After I changed the code to use `WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync`, my client code still works.  Will it continue to work if I use `CreateCheckStatusResponse` instead?

Comment: @ebhh2001-The code should work with `CreateCheckStatusResponse` , but whether to use either of the one is primarily dependent upon the use case scenario i.e.if your client is dependent upon the output of the function then you should stick with `WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync`.`CreateCheckStatusResponse` will give you more control over the function by exposing HTTP management API's  as a json response you can then poll one the api's by name -   `statusQueryGetUri` which will give you the current status of the function and the output once the function executes successfully.

Comment: Aditya Singh, I decided to use orchestrations because they allow me to combine data from multiple sources (blob storage, Cosmos DB, Azure search) and return it to the client as a result of one API call.  The client only wants the json response.   So if I understand you correctly, I should use `WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync`.  Is that right?

Comment: @ebhh2001 - Exactly you should use `WaitForCompletionOrCreateCheckStatusResponseAsync` this will always give you the output and will only expose HTTP management api's if the function fails or exceeds default time out.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Aditya.  I appreciate that!